# Шило на мыло

Tags: фразеология

"Обменять шило на мыло" — откуда пошла эта поговорка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Держим в уме значение этого выражения - "выбирать из плохого худшее". Как полагает В.М.Мокиенко, оборот восходит к диалектному *выменять шило на свайку* (*свайка* - толстый гвоздь или шип с большой головкой для игры в свайку). Логичность внутренней формы этого фразеологизмы несомненна, особенно если учесть отрицательную окраску "нетрудового" термина *свайка* по сравнению с названием инструмента *шило*. Замена компонента *свайка* на *мыло* в сочетании *выменять шило на мыло* регулируется рифмой. (Мокиенко В.М. Славянская фразеология)

Comment: Нда... Придумают же...

Answer (score 8):

Менять шило на мыло -  делать бессмысленный недальновидный обмен: "Я говорю: да чего ты их меняешь-то, Минька? Чего ты все выгадываешь-то? Все они нонче одинаковые, меняй ты их, не меняй. Шило на мыло менять?"  Чтобы легко и аккуратно проколоть кожу шилом, в старину  его действительно приходилось намыливать, т.к. оно было сделано не из нержавейки и поэтому как правило было немного заржавленным, а след-но, шершавым. Поэтому поменять шило на мыло означает поменять одно необходимое на другое, т.е. совершить бессмысленную трансакцию: работать-то все равно нельзя.

Comment: Интересно... Никогда не слышал, чтобы мылили само шило.
Слушайте, а ведь правда... Посмотрел в инете, есть такой совет. Только это не для сапожгников, а для тонкой кожевеной работы. Бумажники там, чехольчики... Седла. Даже специаный сорт мыла был. Седельный...
Век живи, век учись.

Answer (score 2):

Точной версии нет, вообще, насколько знаю, никакой убедительной нет.
Не знаю, может [[@olsa](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa) какую версию выложит, но на мой взгляд здесь чисто фонетическая игра. Из серии фигли-мигли, гоголь-моголь и т.д.

А вот почему именно менять... Очень спорное толкование о бесполезности обоих предметов я как-то не очень разделяю. В бане, например, оно очень даже имеет смысл. Или в сапожной мастерской. кстати, одна из версий как раз и связывает эти вещи с сапожниками. Дратву (сапожную нитку) перед тем как воспользоваться якобы мылили для лучшей "проходимости". Ну и шило, естественно, для тех же целей.  Но в стоящую версию это как-то не складывается.

Еще вспоминается история про то, как солдат шилом брился. С мылом, разумеется. Но это уж совсем сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

МЕНЯТЬ ШИЛО НА МЫЛО
бартерная сделка с допущением ошибки в предварительных расчетах; выбрать из плохого худшее; напрасные хлопоты.
Сколько можно тебе говорить: вяжи менять шило на мыло! Бартеровщик хренов! Ты еще не дал объявление «Меняем два запора на три поноса»?

Насколько я смог накопать в нете, поговорка пошла от сапожных или кожевенных дел мастеров. В работе использовались дратва, шило и мыло. Без шила или мыла работа была невозможной.

Comment: А менять-то зачем? Вы упустили самое важное в вопросе. Остальное более или менее вычисляется.

Answer (score 0):

Менять шило на мыло означает совершенно бессмысленный, бесполезный обмен.
Сапожники и скорняки шилом прокалывают кожу для сшивания, а мылом намыливают нить, которой шьют, чтобы она лучше протаскивалась сквозь слои кожи, не истиралась и не рвалась раньше времени посреди процесса.
Для дела необходимо и то и другое. Без шила нечем колоть отверстия, а без мыла не протащить нитку. То есть обмен одного на другое лишен всякого смысла.

Другой вариант.
Шило символизирует уколы судьбы (острые, болезненные проблемы), а мыло символизирует виселицу (типовой комплект мыло и веревка).
Поменять шило на мыло означает в попытке избавиться от проблем довести дела до виселицы или вместо тяжелых проблем получить смерть.

Answer (score -1):

"Поменять шило на мыло".
Более выгодное на менее выгодное. Мыло смылится со временем, а шило будет служить долго.